# downgrade tensorflow to use cuda 8

Tags: tensorflow

When I run tensorflow I get:

> ImportError: libcublas.so.9.0: cannot open shared object file: No such
>   file or directory

So I'd like to downgrade my tensorflow-gpu to use cuda 8. How do I do that with pip and which version should I download?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Use the `1.4.1` version of tensorflow as

```
pip install tensorflow-gpu==1.4.1
```

Comment: I had cuda9.1 then i removed it and installed cuda8 and tf still wants `libcublas.so.9.1`. Now, I have tf 1.4.1, Cuda 8, and cudnn7. Do i have to downgrade cudnn?
https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#tested_source_configurations

Comment: The official docs for tensorflow 1.4.1 suggests to use CuDNN 6.0 You can try using the latest CuDNN 7.1, and if that does not work you should downgrade it to CuDNN 6.0

Comment: I am using `cudnn 7.1.4`. From the tf documentation https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.5/install/install_sources#optional_install_tensorflow_for_gpu_prerequisites i think cudnn 7 should work. Also, is the `libcublas.so.9.1` problem related to cudnn verion?

Comment: Yes, you need to have cudnn for CUDA 8.0, is that's what you are using

Comment: But on NVIDIA site, Cuda 8 is compatible with cudnn 7.1.4  https://developer.nvidia.com/rdp/cudnn-download
Do you mean that cudnn7.1 won't work on tensorflow1.4 ?

Comment: Like I said, you can try CuDNN 7.1 with CUDA 8.0 for tensorflow 1.4.1, but the official docs suggests using CuDNN 6.0. I am not sure whether 7.1 will work, you can try

Comment: I followed the table in here https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#tested_source_configurations
Installed Cuda8 - cudnn6 - tensorflow1.4 and every thing is working fine.